# Как получить доступ к переменным из config.yml в symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony3

Всем привет, у меня в symfony 3.4 в config.yml 
Определены некоторые произвольные параметры

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

Как мне получить к ним доступ  из php кода? 
Ни как не могу нагуглить.

Comment: У контейнера есть метод `getParameter()`. Воспользуйтесь им для получения своего параметра.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример получения параметра `files_directory` (объявлен в файле *parameters.yml*) из контроллера:

```
$this->getParameter('files_directory')
```